# Android ViewModel is leaking

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel, leakcanary

LeakCanary is telling me that one of my ViewModels is leaking but after playing around for 2 days I can't get the leak to go away.

[Here is why LeakCanary shows](https://i.imgur.com/grs2sJm.mp4)

Here is the Fragment getting the ViewModel

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewBreederViewModel::class.java).apply {
        getStrains(arguments?.getString(BREEDER_ID_KEY, "")!!)
    }
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
class ViewBreederViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val breederRepository = BreederRepository(application)
val strainList = MutableLiveData<List<MinimalStrain>>()

fun getStrains(breederId: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        breederRepository.getMinimalStrains(breederId).observeForever {
            strainList.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the BreederRepository:

```
class BreederRepository(context: Context) {

private val dao: BreederDao
private val breederApi = RetrofitClientInstance.getInstance(context).breederAndStrainIdsApi

init {
    val database: Db = Db.getInstance(
        context
    )!!
    dao = database.breederDao()
}

suspend fun getMinimalStrains(breederId: String): LiveData<List<MinimalStrain>> =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        dao.getMinimalStrains(breederId)
    }
```

}

Here is the Db class

```
@Database(
entities = [Breeder::class, Strain::class],
version = 1,
exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(RoomDateConverter::class)

abstract class Db : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun breederDao(): BreederDao

companion object {
    private var instance: Db? = null

    @JvmStatic
    fun getInstance(context: Context): Db? {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(Db::class) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    Db::class.java, "seedfinder_db"
                )
                    .build()
            }
        }
        return instance
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `observeForever`, which, as the name suggest, will keep observing forever, even after your ViewModel is cleared. Room does not require using a `suspend` method for DAO methods that return a `LiveData` and that is never the right approach in any case - `LiveData` is already asynchronous.

Instead, you should be [transforming your LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata), using your `breederId` as the input to your `strainList` LiveData:

```
class ViewBreederViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val breederRepository = BreederRepository(application)
    private val currentBreederId = MutableLiveData<String>()

    // Here we use the switchMap method from the lifecycle-livedata-ktx artifact
    val strainList: LiveData<String> = currentBreederId.switchMap {
            breederId -> breederRepository.getMinimalStrains(breederId)
    }

    private fun setBreederId(breederId: String) {
        currentBreederId.value = breederId
    }
}
```

Where your `getMinimalStrains` becomes:

```
fun getMinimalStrains(breederId: String): LiveData<List<MinimalStrain>> =
    dao.getMinimalStrains(breederId)
```

And you use it by setting your `breederId` in your UI and observing your `strainList` as before:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewBreederViewModel::class.java).apply {
    setBreederId(arguments?.getString(BREEDER_ID_KEY, "")!!)
}
viewModel.strainList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { strainList ->
  // use your updated list
}
```

If you're using [Saved State module for ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) (which is the default if you're using the latest stable Fragments / Activity libraries), then you can use `SavedStateHandle`, which is automatically populated from your Fragment's arguments and skip the `setBreederId()` entirely:

```
class ViewBreederViewModel(
    application: Application,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val breederRepository = BreederRepository(application)

    // Here we use the switchMap method from the lifecycle-livedata-ktx artifact
    val strainList: LiveData<String> = savedStateHandle
        .getLiveData(BREEDER_ID_KEY) // Automatically populated from arguments
        .switchMap {
            breederId -> breederRepository.getMinimalStrains(breederId)
        }
}
```

Which means your code can simply become:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewBreederViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.strainList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { strainList ->
  // use your updated list
}
```

And if you use the `fragment-ktx` artifact, you can simplify this further to:

```
// Move this to where you declare viewModel
val viewModel: ViewBreederViewModel by viewModels()

viewModel.strainList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { strainList ->
  // use your updated list
}
```

Comment: Wow, an excellent and timely answer by a legend, thanks! Looks like I have some refactoring to do!